# How is ATP converted to adenosine?

Tags: neurophysiology, energy-metabolism, psychoneuropharmacology

I am familiar with [adenosine diphosphate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenosine_diphosphate) (ADP) and [adenosine triphosphate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenosine_triphosphate) (ATP), how one relates to the other, and how each is formed in cellular respiration and photosynthesis, but I am confused as to how regular adenosine is formed.

I was reading an [article on caffeine](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.neubiorev.2016.09.001) which stated:

> Caffeine is structurally similar to adenosine, a neuromodulator, whose formation is dependent on the relative rates of ATP breakdown and synthesis.

From this I concluded that ATP can be changed to regular adenosine, and adenosine back to ATP, but I cannot find anything else on the internet to support my conclusion. I was also wondering *when* and *why* your body would change ADP into adenosine instead of ATP. I assume that AMP plays a role in all of this, and possibly ADA.

I only have a high school level education in biology, so please bear with me. If you do not mind, please include a source in your answer so I can further research on my own. Thanks!

Comment: Adenosine monoposphate can be converted to adenosine by a [5’-nucleotidase](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleotidase).

Comment: @canadianer that set me down the right track for the most part. I have one more question. Wikipedia says that ADP is converted to AMP like this: `2 ADP → ATP + AMP`. What is the name of this process and where does it take place?

Comment: @CardinalSystem that reaction is called adenylate kinase and takes place in almost every living cell.

Comment: Perhaps someone could integrate these comments into a decent answer. Even the poster after he has finished his researches. I'd consider doing it myself but I know next to nothing about adenosine as neuro- signalling molecule, which seems to be the focus of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a full understanding I refer you to the KEGG pathway map which is fairly comprehensive in showing all the metabolic processes that CAN produce Adenosine. 
It's a bit daunting but if you find it on the map [here](https://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?map00230+C00212) it is interactive and you can see the enzymes and pathways involved. If you drill down it brings you to a host of papers and references in primary literature to back things up.

However the dominant process is as follows:

```
   2 ADP <=> ATP + AMP
```

enacted by an [adenylate kinase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenylate_kinase) then:

```
   AMP + H2O <=> Adenosine + phosphate
```

enacted by adenosine 5'-monophosphate phosphohydrolase (a [5'-Nucleotidases](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleotidase) )

Comment: So the nucleotidase can reverse its own hydrolysis to produce AMP, and the adenylate kinase to produce ADP?

Comment: The kinase is certainly reversible with almost an equal balance of each reaction. The nucleotidase I believe is but i don't have a watertight source on it yet.